# Replace SQL results with a charactor

Tags: sql, sql-server, grid, processing

I have a complex script which processes over 200 individual case statements, aggregations or field comparisons. However when the numbers are returned, which are less than 9, I need to replace them with a # or *. Is there a way I can do this across the results or will it need to be included in each processing part?

Comment: are you trying to hide confidential data? Which is the layer your script runs? Application client, or SSMS or some other sql server client?

Comment: No - just that any number less than that is meaningless . so need to hide it

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put the whole case statement (or whatever provides your result) under `REPLACE` function
EDIT: if your output is numeric (or float or integer) you can put the whole statement under a new case, something like below

```
DECLARE @MYTESTTABLE TABLE(ID INT, PRODUCT NVARCHAR(20), PRICE FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @MYTESTTABLE VALUES
(1, 'Product 1', 5.25),
(2, 'Product 2', 15.50),
(3, 'Product 3', 29.90)

SELECT  ID,
        PRODUCT,
        CASE WHEN PRICE < 9 THEN '#' ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PRICE) END AS PRICE
FROM @MYTESTTABLE
```

Output:

```
ID          PRODUCT              PRICE
----------- -------------------- ------------------------------
1           Product 1            #
2           Product 2            15.5
3           Product 3            29.9

(3 rows affected)
```

Comment: will try now and report back